# Golang Redis PubSub sends duplicate messages

Tags: go, websocket, redis, redigo

I am trying to build a feature with the redis pub/sub implementation on golang
but for every client connected to the server (WebSocket) the number of messages published doubles.

```
func (c client) Subscribe() {
    con := initRedis()
    defer con.Close()
    psc := redis.PubSubConn{Conn: con}
    defer psc.Close()
    psc.Subscribe(c.Channel)
    for {
    switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
    case redis.Message:
        fmt.Printf("%s: message: %s\n", v.Channel, v.Data)
        broadcast <- map[string]string{
            "channel": v.Channel,
            "message": string(v.Data),
        }
    case redis.Subscription:
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
    case error:
        log.Println(v)
        psc.Unsubscribe()
    }
}
}

func (m Message) Publish() {
c := initRedis()
defer c.Close()
reply, err := c.Do("PUBLISH", m.Channel, m.Msg)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println("Publishing", m, reply)
}

func initRedis() redis.Conn {
    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // fmt.Println(os.Getenv("REDIS_URL"))
    c, err := redis.DialURL(os.Getenv("REDIS_URL"), redis.DialTLSSkipVerify(true))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // defer c.Close()

    return c
}
```

How do I stop the duplicates?
or what is causing the duplicates.

Comment: Hi Were you able to sort this one out... I am facing similar issue